# Why React skips updating value in component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does React doesn't update `readOnly` in the UI (only) when it equals to 1?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-does-not-update-ui-3ksmvq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A10%2C12)

```js
import './App.css'
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

let value = 0;

function useReadOnly() {
    const [, setCount] = useState(0);
    const timeoutRef = useRef<number>();

    useEffect(() => () => {
        if (typeof timeoutRef.current === 'number') {
            clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
        }
    }, []);

    if (typeof timeoutRef.current === 'number') {
        clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }

    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setCount(c => c + 1);
        value += 1;
    }, 1000);

    timeoutRef.current = timeout;

    return value;
}

function App() {
    const readOnly = useReadOnly();
    console.log('readOnly', readOnly);

    return (
        <p>{readOnly}</p>
    )
}

export default App
```

In the console

```
readOnly 0   // <p>0</p>
readOnly 1   // <p>0</p>
readOnly 2   // <p>2</p>
readOnly 3   // <p>3</p>
...
```

This is a simplification of a more complex code. In the original code `setTimeout()` is an observable.

Comment: `value` is neither a state, nor a reactive value. Why do you expect it to cause a rerender?

Comment: @nullptr a state changes so the hook is rerendered. The value that is returned doesn't have to be a state. OP's code work but it skips one value, that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `StrictMode`

The `App` component is remounted, but the DOM is not updated, hence the difference.

Instead of using a variable `let value = 0`, you can use a ref `const { current: value} = useRef(0);` to synchronize them.